# Best way to folder copying tasks on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, task-scheduler

Here is my dilemma:

- I have a bunch of folders with dates at the end of the folder names (i.e., 2.28 for February 28).
- When the date in the folder name is reached, I want to copy the folder to a certain location.

Here are my ideas:

1. Make a script that extracts the dates from each folder name and checks whether the date is reached, if it has been reached, it copies the corresponding folder to the proper location.
2. Make a batch file for each folder and then add it to the Windows XP task scheduler.

Here are my questions:

1. Does anyone know of software with this functionality?
2. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: 1 is a bit funkey sounding. if the folders are a known, and the date is a known at the time of batch, it should not have to go "through all of the folders", only the ones with that date. So we ask the system the %date% delimit the needed data string , then toss in the foldername with the delimited date info, wildcard anything that doesnt fit, and use that to formulate a copy operation.  Stuff the batch into the task scheduler, and debug forever. Well beyond my skills, but a good coder could pull it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control what the folder name looks like how about

- robocopy C:\src\%DATE%\ C:\dstfolder\

And schedule to run every day?

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I asked instead of doing some other inefficient way.